# How to use docker container as VPN gateway for my host

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a use case where I need to put processes running on my machine (osx) into kubernetes cluster. For years , I have been using teleprence to achieve this untill mac os Sonoma broke things.

Teleprence uses vpn tcp method by using sshutle library under the hood. What that essentially does is proxy all the tcp and dns traffic from all the processes on your machine to the kubernetes cluster.

More details [here](https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence.io/blob/master/docs/v1/discussion/how-it-works.md#)

Now I am able to run teleprence inside a debian container and all the traffic from within the container is able to access cluster and resolve cluster services and pod resources. I am also able to run container using --net=host and and specific ports on host are able to also recieve bidirectional traffic from my
host <->container <-> cluster

But my host is not able to resolve anything from my cluster. How can I make everything from host (tcp, dns traffic) to flow through container so teleprence running in the container can proxy host traffic?

Comment: Currently this question does not fit in SO.

Comment: You are free to choose whatever you want. That doesn't mean this question is fit for SO.